# Cannot install OpenJDK 8

Tags: release-freya, software-installation, apt

I am trying to install OpenJDK 8 in Freya but I can't find in any repository. If I try

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

I get

```
Unable to locate package
```

And when I try to search it via

```
sudo apt-cache search jdk | grep 8
```

I got no results. However version 7 is available in the repo. So do I need to add other repository in order to install Java 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

openjdk8 isn't in the trusty repositories therefore you will have to add another repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-openjdk-8-ubuntu-14-04-12-04-lts/

Comment: I use OpenJDK 8 from this repository: ppa:no1wantdthisname/openjdk-fontfix, which includes fixes for better font rendering. They really look much better than with other JDKs I tried. Installation commands are the same.